# Statistical Mechanics, Entropy, Derivation

Tags: statistical-mechanics, soft-question

While watching Erik Verlinde's [lecture](https://youtu.be/8ovRZuv5Lo8?t=2166) on emergent gravity, he showed formulas from Statistical Mechanics,

[image]

I want to read more about this topic, at an introduction level, which also mentions how to derive them, especially the $dE = T dS$ equation. What are some known, famous, good books that talk about this?

Comment: This is a very very loose analogy if you take special case of the thermodynamic first law and force your explanation on it, not a mainstream. He presents many known results in physics and in between slips his unbased speculative theory of entropic gravity, making it seem as consensus of physical community. The use of equipartition (as I think I saw there) is ridiculous, in that case he clearly speaks out of his field.

Comment: Also the idea is at least 25 years old. See the following article, that derives Einstein field equation from black hole entropy and basic thermodynamic definitions https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.75.1260

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many good introductory books on thermodynamics and you can find this topic everywhere. I personally read Heat and Thermodynamics by Zemansky which gives a good account of thermal physics and some intro to statistical physics.
Then there is Hill, T., An Introduction to Statistical Thermodynamics which is pretty famous introductory book.

Also you can follow first few lectures on statistical mechanics by MIT OCW which reviews thermodynamics. These are quiet good.

Posting a link to ocw page.
https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-333-statistical-mechanics-i-statistical-mechanics-of-particles-fall-2013/